# Встроенная сортировка, в каких случаях можно её обогнать?

Tags: php, алгоритм, сортировка

Возможно вопрос простой, но никакого ответа найти не смог. 
По проекту сравнения сортировок, есть дополнительный вопрос:  
"В каких случаях можно обогнать встроенную в язык сортировку?" 
Тестировал массивы, случайные, частично-упорядоченные, частично-отсортированные, но встроенная PHP сортировка оказывается быстрее всех, она вроде бы основана на Quicksort, но работает уж больно быстрее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я в PHP не компетентен, но об алгоритмах (в С++) могу и поговорить :)

Так вот, конечно, сложность алгоритма важна, кто бы спорил... но есть еще такая вещь, как константа в этой самой сложности. И самым простым примером является сортировка вставками - которая при O(n<sup>2</sup>) отлично работает на почти упорядоченных массивах. Стандартный алгоритм - по крайней мере в ряде реализаций - прибегает к нему уже в самом конце той же быстрой сортировки. Если же знать ситуацию заранее - можно сразу к нему прибегнуть.

У меня на искусственном почти упорядоченном массиве из миллиона элементов получилось

```
стандартная сортировка ~ 101 ms
сортировка вставками   ~ 0,9 ms
```

(Visual C++ 2017 64x)

Весь код - https://rextester.com/NFCBWN86771, тут разница не такая разительная, в 2 раза, а не на 2 порядка, но все равно InsertionSort обгоняет.

Так что ответ - "в некоторых частных случаях" :)

Как вот этот...

Answer (score 1):

При некоторых ограничениях можно сортировать массив с линейной сложностью. Как пример можно привести [сортировку подсчётом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC) или [поразрядную сортировка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0). Такая сортировка может работать быстрее, чем [быстрая сортировка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0), которая имеет линейно-логарифмическую сложность.

Ещё надо понимать, что встроенные в язык функции могут использовать оптимизации, недоступные из самого языка. Особенно это может быть заметно в интерпретируемых языках программирования, каким является `PHP`.